# MessageBox Text from Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I would like to set my `WinForm` controls' text from the Settings.

In case I would like to change in the future the program language, it is quite easy;

Just have to modify the appropriate settings.

One of the `messageBoxes` text has a line break (`\n`).
When I insert its text from Settings, the \n appears as part of the text and there is no line- break.

```
MessageBox.Show(P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotification, 
P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotificationTitle, 
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try Environment.NewLine?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg: Thanks. Can I insert it directly to the string?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg You can not store it as the value in `Setting`

Comment: @lomed Look at my answer, it uses Environment.NewLine, when getting the string from `Setting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
MessageBox.Show(P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotification, 
P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotificationTitle, 
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

With:

```
MessageBox.Show(P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotification.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine)), 
P_Settings.NotificationMessageBoxes.Default.ProcessFinishedNotificationTitle, 
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Replace will check for `\n` and replaces it with: `Environment.NewLine`.
The `Escape sequences` have no meaning within actual string objects. Only when the C# compiler interprets them.

Comment: your answer repat the @Ehsan answer.

Comment: @Max Mommersteeg: Thanks, it works! But why doesn't the string retrieved from Settings know the \n?

Comment: @lomed Look at the time I placed that comment and this isn't exactly the same, I don't create a new string, but directly insert the string from `Setting`, it needs less maintenance and is what the TS asked for.

Comment: @user3165438 The Escape sequences have no meaning within actual string objects. Only when the C# compiler interprets them.

Answer (score 7):

This should work for you

```
string somestring = @"this is some text \n Some more text";
somestring = somestring.Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine);
MessageBox.Show(somestring);
```

Comment: +1 but I would manage at least "\\" sequence too (otherwise if message contains, for example, a path it won't work). Spaces may be used too (" \n " instead of just "\n").